# Find distance of drag event in android

Tags: android

I have two `textView` elements, `android:id="@+id/num1"` and `android:id="@+id/num2"`. I would like the user to drag from `num1` to `num2`, and I would like to find the distance that they covered in the drag. In order to do so, I am trying to use an `onDragListener`, as shown below in my `.java` file. However, I am not sure how to use the `onDragListener` to find the distance dragged, I have looked into `ACTION_DRAG_STARTED` and `ACTION_DRAG_EXITED`, but I can't manipulate those to what I need. If anyone can figure out how to do this, your help would be much appreciated!

The links I was using for drag Listeners
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnDragListener.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

`.java` file

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final View dragLayout = findViewById(R.id.dragLayout);        
        final TextView num1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.num1);
        final TextView num2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.num2);

        dragLayout.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

            //Do something here with the drag event

            return true;
        }
    });
}   

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a private class variable, call it double[] startDrag or something. When you start your drag set startDrag values; do startDrag[0] = dragView.getX(); startDrag[1] = dragView.getY(); then when you are done compare your current position to your stored startDrag variables. Just an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you must keep around the first event until the second event occurs like this:

1. Store the drag start event in a member variable
2. On drag end, calculate the distance between x/y coordinates of drag start event with drag stop event.

EDIT: If you want the STROKE length to be recorded, you must alter your approach:

1. On **drag start**, store the drag start event in a "lastMouseEvent" member variable. Also set a member variable  double mouseStrokeLength to 0.0. This will be used to accumulate the stroke length.
2. On **mouse move**, if the lastMouseEvent is not null, calculate distance from lastMouseEvent to current mouse move event. Add the result distance to mouseStrokeLength. Finally store the current mouse move event as lastMouseEvent, ready for the next round.
3. On **drag end**, add the last calculated distance to mouseStrokeLength and use it. Set lastMouseEvent to null.

Comment: Does this take into account the actual path though? For example, a two different drags can have the same start and stop point, but one could have a longer distance dragged if the user does not go in a straight line.

Comment: No, I did not get that from your question. I will update my answer.